# In R, what's the simplest way to scale a vector to a unit vector?

Tags: r, vector, scaling

In R, what's the simplest way to scale a vector to a unit vector?

For example, suppose

```
>vec
[1] 1 0 2 1
```

And

```
>vec / sqrt(sum(vec^2)) 
[1] 0.4082483 0.0000000 0.8164966 0.4082483
```

is its unit vector.

Is there some built-in function in R for this?

Comment: R seems still weak on matrix algebra functionality

Comment: The base function `scale()` can do `sqrt(sum(x^2)/(n-1))`, but this is not quite what you were looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could make yourself a function:

```
scalar1 <- function(x) {x / sqrt(sum(x^2))}
```

Now just use:

```
> scalar1(vec)
[1] 0.4082483 0.0000000 0.8164966 0.4082483
```

Comment: 0.4082483 is not known and has to be calculated from vec. What I mean is that if there is a built-in function in R for this. For example, if there's some aaa by which aaa(vec, ...) = c(0.4082483, 0.0000000, 0.8164966, 0.4082483)

Comment: From my understanding there's no built in function to do `x / sqrt(sum(x^2))`, but you could make your own quick function. I edited the answer to reflect this. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks anyway. I also know this is a method and just wonder that there may be a built-in function in R for such a common calculation which I haven't found.

Answer (score 3):

The `ppls` package contains the function `normalize.vector`, which does exactly what you want. However, loading a package seems not much simpler than entering the one line definition of the function yourself...

Since 2020-05-04, `ppls` has been retired on CRAN, such that it can no longer be installed with `install.packages("ppls")`. It is still possible to install the latest version with

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ppls/ppls_1.6-1.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
```

I have checked that installation works in R 4.0.0. Note, however, that this does not guarantee that all the functions will work correctly, and even less that they will do so with future versions of R.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ppls` package is not available for R version 4.0.0.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The package has been archived on 2020-05-14: https://cran.r-project.org/package=ppls

Comment: How can anyone use it? Does it work with R's previous versions?

Comment: The problem here is not that the package does not work with R 4.0.0, but that it has been archived on CRAN. You can not install it with `install.packages("ppls")` in any version of R. You can, however, still install the package with `install.packages("install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ppls/ppls_1.6-1.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL)`. I have checked that installation works in R 4.0.0, but that does not guarantee that all the functions will work correctly.